# How do I determine if these functions are odd or even, or neither?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$y=\frac{x^3}{x^4-x^2}$$
$$y=\frac{1}{x^3-1}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{3}{x^2-4}$$
$$y=\frac{x-3}{x+3}$$
$$f(x)=\frac{x^3}{x^5-x^2}$$

I substituted in $-x$ for each $x$, and got my result - however, it is apparently wrong for each one. Do fractions have special rules, or something?  E.g. for the second one, after substituting in $-x$ for $x$ I got $\frac{1}{-x^3 - 1}$, Now the $x$ sign is REVERSED at the denominator, so it would obviously be odd. However, the answer says it is NEITHER.

Am I wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a function to be even you must consider whether $f(-x) = f(x)$ and for it to be odd you require $f(-x) = -f(x)$. Neither of which are true for your second function.

Looking at only the sign of the $x$ as you have is the problem. As a counter example to your idea how would you classify $f(x) = |x|$? Clearly $f(-x) = |-x|$ so the sign in front of the x has changed which would make it odd. Plot the graph of it and you will see that it is even. You must look at the function as a whole and whether it satisfies either of the two conditions.

This is equivalent to the other answer but I don't have enough rep to just comment and explain the part you don't understand.

Comment: But you didn't mention the second condition I talked about in my answer, which is the symmetry of the domain of the function around 0.

Comment: I was attempting to just supplement your answer to aid their understanding because your initial answer was clearly not understood. Perhaps 'equivalent' was too strong a word.

Answer (score 2):

It is neither, first we can see that $$f(-x)=\dfrac{1}{(-x)^3-1}=\dfrac{1}{-x^3-1}\neq -\dfrac{1}{x^3-1}=-f(x).$$ Just because there is a $-$  in the $x$ doesn't mean that it will be odd. To prove that it is neither, you can provide a counter example, so calculate for example $f(-2)$ and compare it with $f(2)$.

Another thing is that for a function to be odd or even, its domain must be symmetric around $0$, so that for each element in its domain, its opposite is also in its domain. The thing that isn't satisfied with your second function since its domain is ${\rm D}_{f}=\mathbb R-\{1\}$ and so $-1$ doesn't have its opposite.

Comment: So for the function above to be ODD, the 1 on the numerator has to be -1 and the -1 on the denominator has to be + 1, essentially, all the signs have to be reversed and not just the x's, yes?

Comment: @Delimit Yes, but even if it were like that the second condition I mentioned isn't satisfied.